# Dynamic adjustment of size of element in splitlayout to browser window

Tags: r, css, shiny

I built a website using splitLayout that lays out elements horizontally, dividing the available horizontal space into multiple parts. I used 'cellWidths = c("1000px", "200px")', so I got an element with width 1000px and a second element with width 200px.

However, what I actually want is that the second element should fit exactly between the right margin of the first element and the right margin of the browser window, so that when the size and/or shape of the browser window is changed, the width of the second element is adjusted accordingly. I tried: 'cellWidths = c("1000px", "calc(100vw-1000px)")', but unfortunately 'calc' cannot be used here.

I thought about using CSS, including something like 'style = "width: "calc(100vw-1000px)"' within the second element, but until now, I did not have any success by trying that.

The complete code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  splitLayout(
    cellWidths = c("1000px", "200px"),
    cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 6px; white-space: normal;"),

    fluidPage(
      style = "border: 1px solid silver; height: 627px;"
    ),

    fluidPage(
      style = "border: 1px solid silver; height: 627px",
      p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut alterum facilis disputationi vis, summo percipitur sed ea. Stet senserit persequeris at duo, vis atqui vituperata ex, et has omittam expetenda persequeris. Id usu causae meliore, dolorem lucilius perpetua id vim. Vim at homero timeam viderer, dicunt concludaturque ea eum. Tempor ceteros facilisi ei pro, ea tantas adipisci scribentur vix.")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not an R programmer, and while I can can take guesses at what 'splitLayout' and 'fluidPage' accomplish for you, I don't know enough to tell you definitively what the fix is.

However, what you're describing can be achieved via CSS by using flexbox. In case you're unfamiliar with it, here's some good information:

- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/